# IF/ELSE Button OnClick based on info from a table

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button

First of all, I'm a complete newb and this code could be way off so please bare with me.
I'm trying to get the button to have a different hyperlinks based on the text in a table. So if the table answer says Blue, the button click will go to HTML1 and if it says RED then it will go to HTML2. Is this possible? I've been running scenarios in my head and this logically makes sense to me, but obviously isn't working.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>TITLE</strong></td>
<td id="colortype" type="text">Blue<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button class="btn" id="button">Find Colors</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (document.getElementById("colortype").textContent == "Blue"){
        document.getElementById("button").window.open("HTML1")
    }
    else (document.getElementById("colortype").textContent = "Red"){
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = 'HTML2';  
    }

   </script>
```

Comment: PSA: `=` and `==` are *vastly* different. Pay close attention to details like this. It'll burn you if you don't. You'll need to develop an eye for this and always check that you're using the right one.

Comment: You need to describe your idea more specifically. I recommend you go through some web development tutorial.

Comment: Also not that JS doesn't use `==` unless you _absolutely_ need coercion. JS has `=` for assignment and `===` for comparison. `==` is a super special operator for comparison with auto-type-coercion that (almost) always lead to weird edge case bugs because `"content"` is neither true, nor false, when using `==`.

Comment: You don't put a condition after `else`. If you want to test another condition, use `else if`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("button").window.open("HTML1")` is not how you set what happens when clicking on the button. You need to add an event listener.

Comment: You have some basic syntax misunderstandings. SO is not a tutoring service, you have to learn the basics first.

Comment: The event listener can then contain the `if` statements and do `window.location = "URL"` to link to another URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```js
 function getColor(){
    switch (document.getElementById("colortype").textContent.trim()){
    case "Blue":
        location.href="HTML1";
      break;
   case "Red":
        location.href="HTML2";
      break;
   default:
        break;
  }
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>TITLE</strong></td>
    <td id="colortype" type="text">Blue<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class="btn" id="button" onclick="getColor()">Find Colors</button>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, however when I tried replacing the HTML with actual URLs, the button still doesn't work. I really appreciate your help and I realized that my code was completely off.

Comment: What is your actual URL? What do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: I have updated the code, you may try again.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! It works now. I really appreciate your time for helping me on this. I know I have lots to learn since I just started coding and Java is especially hard for me to understand. I want to learn, but don't know where to start. There are just so many tutorials out there its hard to begin where. But thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me with this.

Comment: Javascript is completely different from Java. To learn javascript in a browser(so-called client side), first, you need to know the basic structure of an HTML page and how to use various HTML elements, This is because the client-side javascript is all about HTML elements manipulation.